# Child table with 100% width extends parent

Tags: html, css

at the moment I am trying to create a child table, that can have a width of more than 100% of the parent. Therefor they should have a scrollbar. But, when I try this with my following css the child has a scrollbar and for some reason extends the parent containers width. It works fine, if I use a static size like 500px, but it fails with a width of 100%.

### HTML

(simplified)

```
<main class="main">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</main>
```

### CSS

(simplified)

```
.main {
    margin: 0 10%;
    padding: 00;
    width: 80%;
    display: table;
}

table {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

### Snippets

#### Example with static width of 500px

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .main {
      margin: 0 10%;
      padding: 00;
      width: 80%;
      display: table;
    }
    
    table {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 500px;
      display: block;
      overflow-x: auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="main">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>A very very very veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong line</td>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

#### example with dynamic width of 100%

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .main {
      margin: 0 10%;
      padding: 00;
      width: 80%;
      display: table;
    }
    
    table {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%; /* PROBLEM */
      display: block;
      overflow-x: auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="main">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>A very very very veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong line</td>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `table-layout:fixed;` <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout)</sup>.  the automatic layout may give unexpected result.

> Fixed table layout
>
> With this (fast) algorithm, the horizontal layout of the table **does not depend on the contents of the cells**; it only depends on the table's width, the width of the columns, and borders or cell spacing.

As a side note, the same issue happen with or without `width:100%`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.main {
  margin: 0 10%;
  padding: 00;
  width: 80%;
  display: table;
}

table {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>A very very very veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong line</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</main>
<main class="main" style="table-layout: fixed;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>A very very very veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong line</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</main>
```